# Oozie job taking longer than scheduled interval

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am scheduling an Oozie MapReduce job to run every 15 minutes. I wonder what would happen if each job will take longer than that set time? Will it result in a job backlog? Or Oozie will create a new task / thread / fork for the new job while the previous one is still running?

Comment: check out the edited version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oozie won't run the next job before the previous one is over. If the first job takes more than 15 minutes to execute then the next one will be run after scheduled time. So scheduled time and running time may be different in Oozie.

EDIT:

Anyway, the described behaviour is default only and can be changed. You can set `concurrency` property from `controls` block to more than 1, and the next job will be run even the first one is still running. Check my answer on similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744487/how-to-force-coordinator-action-materialization-at-specific-frequency/31746057#31746057)